# Detect USB thumb flash drive insertions?

Tags: macos, usb, flash-memory

Is there a way to get a list of recent times when a USB thumb flash drive was inserted? I'm using Sierra.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was easy.

```
log show | grep ": mounted "
```